# How to copy all Lead View elements to custom entity in crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

Is it possible to copy all my view elements from lead Enntity to customized entity.
              If i create new elements in lead form then save close then i need to have those
              listview contents in my custom entity also. Is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking; how can I map data from one record to another?

You could do this via:

- A workflow.
- A plugin.
- Relationship attribute mapping. ([Field Mapping in Microsoft Dynamic CRM 2011](http://www.xrmlabs.com/AboutUs/XRMsBlog/tabid/65/EntryId/27/Field-Mapping-in-Microsoft-Dynamic-CRM-2011.aspx)).